# Remove occurrence of Unicode character \u{ef} from String In Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, unicode

Remove occurrence of Unicode character  `\u{ef}` from `String` In Swift 3.

Example String:-  `"\u{ef}\n \n\u{ef}\n \n\u{ef}"`

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replacingOccurrences` on your `String`:

```
let str = "\u{ef}\n \n\u{ef}\n \n\u{ef}".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
let newStr = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
print(newStr) //
```

Comment: I also tried this function for string replace occurrence function but not getting result... For Example: -   var trimmedStr = UIUtils.removingWhiteSpace(self.composeBar.textView.text as NSString) as String
         trimmedStr = resultString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
        if trimmedStr > 0
        {
            ChatPersistentService.persistChatDate(self.threadInfo.threadId.stringValue(), txt: trimmedStr,isPersistingChat: true)
        }

Comment: @BalKrishanYadav, the error you have in your case is the `removingWhiteSpace`. I have updated my example with removing white spaces too.

Comment: @Rashwan L Any help for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586825/swift-3-replace-or-format-unicode-characters-multiply-from-long-text

Comment: @BalKrishanYadav, did you find a solution yet and if my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Comment: @NikolaLukic, I´ll have a look!